# pygame window not opening with no errors

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.10

I have tried multiple simple pygame programs, found on the internet, which run with no error messages, but the window for the game doesn't open.
This is my code:

```
# Simple pygame program

# Import and initialize the pygame library
import pygame
import os
os.environ['SDL_AUDIODRIVER'] = 'dsp'

pygame.init()

# Set up the drawing window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

# Run until the user asks to quit
running = True
while running:

    # Did the user click the window close button?
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # Draw a solid blue circle in the center
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 75)

    # Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

# Done! Time to quit.
pygame.quit()
```

And this is the output:
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.2, Python 3.10.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html

I have tried multiple different programs found online but the output is always the same.
**I am using VS Code through Github.dev, might this be the problem?**

Comment: *I am using VS Code through Github.dev, might this be the problem?* - Yes, you can't run pygame in a browser, but you can use [pygbag](https://pypi.org/project/pygbag/)

Answer (score -1):

You should have the pygame.display.flip() in a while loop with a clock, so that each frame is redrawn to the screen. This will work:

```py
import pygame
import os

os.environ["SDL_AUDIODRIVER"] = "dsp"
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #set the clock
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500, 500])

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Fill the background with white
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # Draw a solid blue circle in the center
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (250, 250), 75)

    # Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # clock
    clock.tick(60)
```

Of course, it's recommended to have this is separate functions so game logic can be implemented cleanly.

Comment: No this is not the problem. Your answer is wrong. The problem is clearly mentioned in the question *"I am using VS Code through Github.dev, might this be the problem?"* - However, pygame cannot be run in a browser.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the same problem persists. I am now trying to run the code on VS Code its self, to see if it will work like that, but the python installer won't work.